# Storing an INI file in memory

Tags: coldfusion, ini, railo

I am writing an application that uses an ini file to store all status codes (errors, success codes, etc.)  A very simple version is this:

```
[success]
000=Status code not found.

[error]
000=Error code not found.
001=Username/Password not found.
```

And my CF Component to work with that uses the following code:

```
component  hint="Set of tools to interact with status codes."{
    public function init(string codefile) any{
        this.codefile = Arguments.codefile;
    }

    public function getCodeString(string type, string code) string{
        var code = getProfileString(Variables.codefile, Arguments.type, Arguments.code);
        return code;
    }
}
```

What I assume happens when I call the getProfileString is that Railo opens the file, searches for the key and returns the value.  So as my application grows and I have a lot more codes, I expect that this process will slow down.  So is there a way that I can open the file in my init method and read it all into the variables scope, and call the getProfileString from there?

Comment: Ok.  I couldn't see why you couldn't use an array to store the data, then get the error codes from that...

Comment: Well I could use an array, but an ini file is easier to dive into and edit and view, especially if someone emails me and says they received error code #xxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even parse your ini file in onApplicationStart and push the data into application scope like recommended for a XML file by @Sergii, if you want to stick with the .ini approach.

Do something like that:

```
var sections = getProfileSections(variables.codeFile);
var sectionEntries = [];
var indx = 0;
for (key in sections){
    sectionEntries = listToArray(sections[key]);
    application[key] = {};
    for (indx=1; indx <= arraylen(sectionEntries); indx++){
            application[key][sectionEntries[indx]] = getProfileString(variables.cfgFile,key,sectionEntries[indx]);
    }
}
```

haven't tested this on Railo, but it should work on ColdFusion 9 at least

Comment: This looks like the best solution for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Railo there's possibly easiest solution: put the file into the RAM filesystem.

So full path to the file will look like `ram:///some/path/to/config.ini`.

Obviously, you need to write the file into the RAM first, possibly on first request.

So slightly modified version of the component may look this way:

```
component  hint="Set of tools to interact with status codes."{

    public function init(string codefile, string.ramfile) any{
        variables.codefile = arguments.codefile;
        variables.ramfile = arguments.ramfile;
    }

    public function getCodeString(string type, string code) string{

        if (NOT fileExists(variables.ramfile)) {
            fileCopy(variables.codefile, variables.ramfile);
        }

        return getProfileString(variables.ramfile, arguments.type, arguments.code);

    }
}
```

Please note that I've changed `this.codefile` to the `variables.codefile` in the `init`.

Any way, I'm also not sure ini file is the most handy and maintainable solution. You need to parse it each time any way, right? If you need a *file* config, use XML. Just parse it in `onApplicationStart` and push the data into the application scope.